# How to implement Google Analytics click event tracker in Unbounce?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events

When a button click happens, send a hit to Google Analytics. But how without using "onClick.." code HTML? Can I just add some Javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! First of all, why do people downvote without leaving a constructive comment? Second of all, can you please show some coding attempts at what you've tried and the errors you got? We can't just provide a solution without first knowing that you've put effort into coming up with your own solution first. Hope you understand.

Comment: Sure i understand. Thank you by make me reflect about!

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution, easier than I think. Not so customizable as I want but works fine.

It's now possible to integrate using the Script Manager of Unbounce. It makes everything more easily. You don't need to re-write the code or put a different JavaScript. By default, every click or action are tracked and sent to GA.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old but wanted to let people know that there are ways we can integrate custom javascript code in Unbounce.

**1. Using Scripts Manager**
    - If script is also shared by other pages, then create it using `Scripts Manager`
    - When script is ready, enable it for the variant/pages where you want this script to load

**3. Using Custom HTML Code Block**
    - This method can be used when script is very specific to page only.
    - create new custom HTML code, and place your javascript code inside `<script>your js code</script>` tag.